# Pandas remove column name above index column name

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dataset

[image]

How to remove 'movie title' and obtain a regular dataset with columns: [user_id, age, occupation, etc... ?

I tried:

```
final_df = final_df.rename_axis(None, axis="columns")
```

but this leaves an empty space where 'movie title' is.

Comment: Maybe `final_df.rename_axis(None, axis="columns").reset_index()` ?

Comment: yes this makes sense, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try?:

```
df.reset_index().drop(columns=['movie title'],inplace=True)
```

Comment: This creates a new column 'movie title' but after that for some reason I cannot drop it :(

Comment: See updated answer above

Comment: This won't work `movie title` is not a column, you need `final_df.rename_axis(columns=None)` to remove this label.

Comment: @mozway - it is a column after reset_index

Comment: No, it's not. OP should provide a reproducible example, but I can assure you by the looks of the image it's not a column.

Comment: @mozway - with your high expertise I am sure you are right :-)